# Is there a problem when the Scilab karkarkar solver terminates with no iterations and exit flag 1?

Tags: solver, scilab

When I run karmarkar I get the following output:

operation -: Warning adding a matrix with the empty matrix will give an empty matrix result.

When I look at iter, exitflag and fopt I get 0, 1 and 25.905369 respectively. Also xopt=x0. Is this because x0 was in fact xopt so karmarkar could not find any improvement?　Or is the problem too large? (it has 1296 decision variables)

Comment: The warning about a substraction with an empty matrix denotes a problem with your code building the matrices of your linear program. Fix this first (try to identify the line where the problem occurs).